# Better solution on PDF generator for using as a mail attachment in yii2

Tags: email, yii2, jspdf

i used jspdf plugin to generate pdf file and passed to the controller using ajax. In controller i mailed the pdf as body now i want to mail the pdf as attachment.
Is there any better way to generate pdf than jspdf?
I generated pdf using the following code and sent using ajax

```
<script>
   function demoFromHTML() {
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
      source = $('#content')[0];
      specialElementHandlers = {
         '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
         }
      };
      margins = {
         top: 80,
         bottom: 60,
         left: 40,
         width: 522
      };
      pdf.fromHTML(
            source,
            margins.left,
            margins.top, {
               // y coord
               'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
               'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },
            function (dispose) {
               // pdf.save('ticket');
               var pdfBase64 = pdf.output();
               var email= 'check@email.com';
               $.ajax({
                  'url': baseUrl + '/site/email',
                  'method': 'post',
                  'data': {
                     'pdfBase64': pdfBase64,
                     'email':email
                  },
                  'success': function (result) {
                     if (!result == 'true') {
                        notify('Sorry Email NOt sent', 'danger');
                     } else {
                        notify('Ticket sent', 'success');
                     }
                  },
                  'error': function (error) {
                     notify('Server Error. Sorry Email Not Sent', 'danger');
                  }
               });

            }, margins
      );


      // $('#email').val(pdfBase64);
   }
</script>
```

Using following code i sent mail in controller

```
 if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                $post = Yii::$app->request->get();
                $email = $post['data']['email'];
                $name = 'Smart Bus';
                $subject = 'Booked Ticket';
                $base64 = $post['data']['pdfbase64'];
                $decoded = base64_decode($base64);
                Email::sendTo($email, $name, $subject, file_put_contents('invoice.pdf', $decoded));
            }
```

Comment: Are you using Swiftmailer extension here? You are not providing enough info to help you and you are asking two questions instead of focusing on just one. If this is Swiftmailer extension [here is the way to attach file to mail](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing#file-attachment).

Comment: @Bizley it is php mailer

Answer (score 0):

If you asked for another package than jspdf, It would be great if you use [TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf) as it is more stared and used(more famous). Also it is PHP PDF Library (server side) however the jspdf is client side one.